# Extending RoboActivity gives ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, roboguice

I am trying to use RoboGuice2.0 with my android project.
I am working on android-studio and have **guice-3.0-no_aop.jar**, **javax.inject.jar**, **jsr305-1.3.9.jar** and **roboguice-2.0.jar** included in my classpath.

My Code is :

```
 public class MainActivity extends RoboActivity {

  //    @InjectView(R.id.textView) TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Log.d("Text View value ",tv.getText().toString());

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

when I run this on my emulator, I get following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find   

class "com.example.app.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.app-2.apk
```

My Menifest file is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.app"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What I am missing here? What can be the cause of error? I have been searching for hours on internet but unable to resolve the issue

Comment: Solved it ? I am also struggling with it

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

add it to resolve this exception.

Comment: I've also tried it, but got no success. I also now attached my manifest.xml to my post.